# How to iterate an object and return values ones per items in a brace

Tags: javascript

I have a object containing data from like this:

```
let data = {"A":"Alpha", "B":"Bravo", "C":"Charlie"};
```

Using the above object, I need to iterate but return the items using the key name like this:

```
for(let key in data) {
   if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

 // Get the data here by the key name:
     alert(data['A'] + ' ' + data['B'] + ' ' + data['C']);

    }
}
```

Or this way:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key,index) {
   alert(data['A'] + ' ' + data['B'] + ' ' + data['C']);
});
```

Both forms will output this: Which is correct because the object has 3 items.

```
Alpha Bravo Charlie
Alpha Bravo Charlie
Alpha Bravo Charlie
```

without using a `break;` and with Vanilla JavaScript (No `JQuery`)  How can I simply get:

```
Alpha Bravo Charlie
```

Comment: You are looping and then decide to completely ignore the key you get in each iteration, and decide to specify yourself the key as a hard-coded literal. You need to make up your mind what you want to do.

Comment: @trincot: Thanks for the kind comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` on `Object.keys()` and return values.

```js
let data = {"A":"Alpha", "B":"Bravo", "C":"Charlie"};
var values = Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key]);

console.log(values.join(' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

ES6/7 way:

```
Object.values(data).join(' '));
```

ES5:

```
Object.keys(data).map(function(item) { return data[item]; }).join(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are manually extracting all the data upon each loop iteration by asking for the `A`, `B` and `C` key values - - that's why you see all 3 values upon each iteration.

Both versions of your code will work just fine if you just use your looping variable and get only the one key value that the loop is enumerating at that moment:

```js
let data = {"A":"Alpha", "B":"Bravo", "C":"Charlie"};

for(let key in data) {
   if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     // Get the data here by the key name:
     console.log(data[key]);
   }
}

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key,index) {
   console.log(data[key]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

```js
var data = {"A":"Alpha", "B":"Bravo", "C":"Charlie"};

var result = Object.keys(data).reduce(function(acc, cVal){
return acc+ " "+data[cVal];
}, "");
console.log(result);

//ES6 snippet
var result = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, cval)=>acc+" "+data[cval], "");
console.log(result);
```

Hope this helps :)